# Azure Firewall logs not showing the network rule name

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring, paas

Is there anyway to show the network rule name in the output
[image: Query]

I have read that this has been added in the preview release and followed the configuration to enable that from the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/firewall/firewall-preview

**Although its showing as the feature is installed but still the logs are not showing the effect**. Any help would be highly appreciated.

[image: Pic2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind...Issue got resolved.